# Best way to save options in vb

Tags: vb.net, configuration, settings

I'm making an app in vb and I'd like to read and write some options to file. 
All needed files are stored in an external (configurable) folder so the built in settings thing isn't an option. 
What would you recommend for saving variables (mostly strings) to a file that can be anywhere and can be read/written to at app runtime.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Let me explain a little better:
I'd like to make a menu from which the user could change some settings for the program. Of course I'd like to make the settings to save for the next time the user runs the program.

I've tried the following:

The .NET settings thing - Always saves to some weird folder

Nini (.ini library) - I need the program to be portable and work on any PC without an libs

Some function I found that reads txt files (setting=value) *I'll get the link as soon as I get to my PC* - Read only

Comment: You can save them in an xml file or in a txt with json inside application path.

Comment: There are quite a few options to read/write files in VB.NET (depending even of the exact type of files). Alternatively, you might consider the option of a database. There is no absolutely better option; depending upon the exact conditions, it might be better to rely on certain approach. Also bear in mind that a minimal understanding (or some pre-research) is one of the pre-requisites to ask here. Please, explain better what you want and show us what you have tried sofar.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can work for your situation:

Create a structure (or a class) for your options:

```
Public Structure MyOptions
    Dim option1 As Integer
    Dim option2 As Integer
    Dim option3 As String
End Structure
```

Then do something like this:

```
Dim options As New MyOptions
Dim path As String = "settings.cfg"
Dim jsonString As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options, Formatting.Indented)

If File.Exists(path) = False Then
    File.WriteAllText(path, jsonString) 'if dile doesn't exist save initial jsonString
Else
    jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path) 'read options from file
End If

'load structure with values from file
options = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyOptions)(jsonString)
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
Dim x as integer = options.option1
Dim s as string = options.option3
```

Your initial settings.cfg file will look like this:

```
{
  "option1": 0,
  "option2": 0,
  "option3": null
}
```

After changing your options values:

```
options.option1 = 5
options.option3 = "test"
```

You can save it to file like this:

```
jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options, Formatting.Indented)
File.WriteAllText(path, jsonString)
```

and the new file will look like this:

```
{
  "option1": 5,
  "option2": 0,
  "option3": "test"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can save your options by add it to your program settings:
1-After you open your project, go to "Project" menu
2-Click in the before the last: .......settings
3-You can add new items ex: type:String if you want to save your option that it's in a textbox.